# multitasking and return to application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

on iphone with multitasking and iOS 4.x i run my app it work properly, now if i hit the home button (send a sms) and then double click the home button to return to my app i've notice that the app run like the first time not continue where i left it what is the solution to return to the point where you click the home button.

thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest version of xCode, and are you using the 4.0 SDK? If your SDK is anything lower than 4.0, it will not use multitasking (yet it will appear in the list) and it will simply close and open as normal.

Comment: i use the 3.2.4 xcode version not 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make sure you're implementing the multitasking app delegate callbacks- check out the protocol reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.